# Toggle (reset) burger, remove (reset) menu, all from submenu link .on(click) (tap)

Tags: jquery, css, submenu

I've been drinking from the "firehose" and am stuck on perhaps a simple problem. I have a ul menu that changes (using jquery .addClass) to a mobile slider menu. At 800px the desktop menu disappears and a menu "burger' appears. When clicked/tapped, the burger toggles the slider menu in from the left. This all works fine, but clicking a submenu link on an anchor tag leaves the menu in place, overlapping the content. The burger must be clicked/tapped again to make the menu retreat outside the window.

I'm looking for a solution to essentially toggle/reset the burger during the submenu li a (anchor tag) click event, that removes the menu, while still allowing it to be used again on the same page (for other anchors).

So far my solutions have removed the menu on click, but failed to allow that specific submenu ul to be used/seen again. Plus, the burger doesn't get toggled to its original setting. Another current experiment removed the menu, left the hover going and didn't toggle the burger, so it became out of sync with the slider. Any suggestions is much, much appreciated!

P.S. Anchor tags are under "CUSTOMIZE" link. "myFunction" script toggles the "burger"

Link to view test page:
http://www.cardscreative.com/cc2017/test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Cards Creative - Telling stories. Beautifully.</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="test2.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="css/fixedsticky.css">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400,600,700,800|Cormorant+Garamond:400,500' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script> function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");   }
    </script> 

</head>

<body>
<!--- Begin Nav & Burger Menu --->
    <input  id="menuToggle" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="menuToggle">
        <div id="burger"  onclick="myFunction(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"><p>MENU</p></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </label>


<!--- Slide/Nav Mobile --->    
    <div class='nav'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>CUSTOMIZE <span style="font-family:Arial Black;">&#x25BA;</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#top'>Design Options</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#colors'>Colors</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#fonts'>Fonts</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#compare'>Font Comparison</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>   

        </ul>
    </div> 

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/cardsCreative.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#menuToggle {
    display: none;
}

#menuToggle:checked ~ .mobile {
    position: fixed; left: 0; top:0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 801px) {
  #burger { visibility:hidden;}
    .nav {display:block;}
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #burger { visibility: visible;}
  .nav {display:none;}
```

Relevant Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth < 800) {
        $('.nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('mobile');
    }
    if (viewportWidth > 800) {
        $('.mobile').removeClass('mobile').addClass('nav');
    }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#burger').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav').removeClass('nav').addClass('mobile');
    });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav').children('ul').find('ul').on('click', function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').trigger('click');
        $('myFunction').toggle(); 
    });

});
```

Comment: In scratch.html line 27, try replace this $(this).find('ul').toggle(); with this $("#menuToggle").toggle();

Comment: Thanks for the help yjs, but the code's a "no-go". I'm not sure where you're seeing the code "$(this).find('ul').toggle(); " above. I tried replacing the last line of the checkbox function with your suggested code, and it only reveals the actual checkbox above the burger - it doesn't toggle the burger back to a 3-line menu icon. Specifically looking to target the .toggle("change") function from a submenu link .